# ¿Como puedo crear un IsMouseOver trigger en C# usando codigo (WPF)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, trigger

Antes que nada, llevo solo 2 dias aprendiendo sobre formularios WPF asi que aun soy muy novato.

He creado una ventana con 2 botones que cambian el tamaño de su letra y el color cuando pasas el raton por encima. Este es el MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_boton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_boton"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Boton 1">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Boton 2">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Como podria hacer para simular esto pero en codigo (MainWindow.xaml.cs)?

Comment: @Benito-B perdona y gracias por avisar, no sabia que estaba en la comunidad en español. Ya está traducida :)

Comment: No problemo, pasa más a menudo de lo que te creerías ;)

Answer (score 0):

Esto es sencillo de hacer pero dependiendo de lo que quieres puede tomar un poco de trabajo extra, lo que debes hacer es crear un elemento `Style` y configurar su comportamiento, luego se lo aplicas al control que quieres:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Boton 1">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Esta es la estructura de tu primer botón (lo llamaré button1), si te fijas, CONTIENE un elemento `Style`, para lograr esto a través de código tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
public void ChangeStyleExample()
{   
    Style style = new Style(typeof(Button), button1.Style);
    
    Trigger t = new Trigger();
    t.Property = Button.IsMouseOverProperty;
    t.Value = true;
    
    Setter setter1 = new Setter();
    setter1.Property = Button.BackgroundProperty;
    setter1.Value = Brushes.Blue;
    t.Setters.Add(setter1);
    
    Setter setter2 = new Setter();
    setter2.Property = Button.FontSizeProperty;
    setter2.Value = 25;
    t.Setters.Add(setter2);
    
    Setter setter3 = new Setter();
    setter3.Property = Button.ForegroundProperty;
    setter3.Value = Brushes.Red;
    t.Setters.Add(setter3);
    
    style.Triggers.Add(t); 
    
    button1.Style = style;
}
```

Y ya con eso debería funcionar.
Solo debes ajustarlo, optimizarlo y crear uno para tu otro botón, recuerda (si es que aún no lo sabes) que si necesitas aplicar un mismo estilo a más de 1 botón, o a todos los botones, es preferible que uses un Diccionario de Recursos.